# Add sourceSet and dependencies to a gradle build script which inherits from main

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have an existing application which already supports different environments like desktop, android and such. Now I want to additionally provide the same functionallity over a rest interface. I though I might just add a different sourceSet + configuration. I could do this using just add a new submodule but I thought I might also be able to use different configuration in gradle like for "desktop". But somehow I can not get the spring boot dependency into my "server" classpath. How could I achieve a source and dependency setting which inherits from "main" but adds additional sources and libraries?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.0'
        classpath 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins:javafx-gradle-plugin:8.7.0'
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

springBoot {
    customConfiguration = "server"

}

sourceSets {
    server {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/server/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/server/resources']
        }
        compileClasspath += main.output + configurations.server
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + configurations.server
    }
}

configurations {
    server.extendsFrom(compile)
}

dependencies {
    // some dependencies ...

    // Only for the spring webserver
    server "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very similar to my [java flavours plugin](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours)

```
apply plugin: 'com.lazan.javaflavours'
javaFlavours {
    flavours = ['free', 'paid']
}
```

The plugin creates source sets for each flavour which inherit from the main. The plugin also creates compile, test and jar tasks for each flavour. Interesting code [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursPlugin.groovy)